# macOS Big Sur: bypasses login screen when woken from sleep, doesn't require password at all

Tags: macos, sleep, login, macbook-pro, macos-bigsur

Anyone know how I can stop this happening?!

- I have checked that no apps are preventing sleep in Activity Monitor.
- I have not changed the settings or anything.  This is only since the upgrade to Big Sur.
- I have toggled require password off/on since this post... literally happened again this morning, no password required.  Was definitely sleeping!

This is so dumb, but several times now I have opened the lid of my 2017 MBP with Touch Bar and I have been immediately at the desktop, with no password required to login.

What a ridiculous bug.

Thanks.

Comment: The system preference to control require-password-on-wake-from-sleep is the most obvious place to start (toggle it a few times).  But, more importantly, make sure that the Mac is actually sleeping in the first place.  Try to reproduce it by forcing it to sleep w/ the lid open.  If that works as expected, Google how to read the logs to see if your Mac is really sleeping (it's a little hard to see, so try it with the forced sleep first).  Then make sure the Mac is really sleeping when you close the lid.  If it's still awake, that could be why you're not prompted for a password.

Comment: Did as you said and it happened again this morning, any other ideas?

Comment: It probably is a new macOS bug, but one more thing to try.  Have you used `pmset -g log` to look at the sleep log?  If so, look for a "DarkWake from Deep Idle" entry just before you opened the lid.  It's possible that the Mac is waking up for a "maintenance" period, you're opening the lid, and it "forgets" that it was sleeping and should prompt for a password.  Still, that would be a bug.  Maybe try one of the `pmset` reset options?

Comment: If you put your Mac to sleep with Apple menu > Sleep, wait a few seconds and then press a key, do you see the login window? Have you enabled Power Nap (System Preferences > Battery > Power Adapter)?

Comment: I do see the login window yes, I have it set to show immediately after sleep. Power nap is disabled - has been ever since they introduced the feature.  I am beginning to wonder if it's anything to do with the app KeepingYouAwake - despite me disabling it on the menu bar. https://keepingyouawake.app

Comment: This is happening to me. I have a 2013 MacBook Pro that I have been using for ~ 10 years, and this has been working fine, until I upgraded to Big Sur about a month ago.